# How to create a pdf with the name of the session and the products in the shopping cart?

Tags: php

I have a web page where you buy a series of things and then I need to generate a pdf, I am trying but for some reason the names of the things and the variables do not print it to me.
this is my code for PDF
The total price and VAT variables are taken from the php cart file that has these variables. The second problem is to make each round of the foreach give a name to the variables, so the first round is pp1 pt1, the second round pp2 pt2 and so on.

```
  <?php

include 'conn.php';
session_start();
require'Pdf/fpdf.php';
foreach ($_SESSION['cesta'] as $codigo => $producto){
$pti = ${producto['titulo'];
$ppi = ${producto['precio'];
}
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->Cell(100, 20, '', 0, 1);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 16);
$pdf->setX(50);
$d = rand(1, 99999);
$pdf->Cell(100, 10, '      Factura ', 0, 1, 'c');
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 12);
$pdf->Cell(90, 10, $_SESSION['name'], 0, 1, 'l');
$pdf->Cell(90, 10, $pt1, 0, 0, 'l');
$pdf->Cell(90, 10, $ppp1, 0, 1, 'l');
$pdf->Cell(90, 10, $pt2, 0, 0, 'l');
$pdf->Cell(90, 10, $ppp2, 0, 1, 'l');
$pdf->Cell(90, 10, $total, 0, 1, 'l');
$pdf->Cell(90, 10, $precioIiva, 0, 1, 'l');
$pdf->Cell(90, 10, $sumaTotal, 0, 1, 'l');
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

Comment: You have typos, `${producto` remove the `{`

Comment: it isnt only the wrong

Comment: Add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` under `session_start()` to throw a readable error, just remember to set it to `error_reporting(0)` for production

Comment: With that you read the name of the session and the product but not the price. This variable is not read by $ pp1 = $ product ['price'];

Comment: is `$producto` an array?

Comment: I'm not sure, this is the code I have  in other php  $_SESSION['cesta'][$_POST['producto']] = $producto;